# Not able to generate JWT token by Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am a bit new to generate OAuth JWT tokens. I have been trying to implement an Authorization Server by using Spring Boot OAuth. The problem I am facing is I am not able to generate the JWT token, rather it generates a simple token and not JWT one.

[image]

I have created the project in GitHub . Please see the link
https://github.com/jainaks2010/OAuth2AuthorizationServer

I am using POSTMan to generate -
[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming your screenshot is what is actually generated, it looks like a parsed JWT token

Comment: Can you please check my code in GitHub for any obvious errors. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any obvious error. Can you say more about how you get the parsed token? Which API calls you are doing, etc...

Comment: I am using Open JDK 11 to generate my jks file. I am using a simple UserDetails service to check a user's username and password and a simple ClientDetailsService that uses inMemory . I am using JWT Token store and providing it to AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the converter to the endpoints like so:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccesTokenConvertor()) // <-- This one
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But any reasons why we need to double reference it as the token store already has the token converter object. Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: One is for the `TokenStore` which is where tokens are "saved" on the server, the other is the converter for endpoints. This means that you can encode one and not the other or have different converters for each. i.e. You might want a different converter for TokenStore when using a DB behind so it is not so easy to read them from DB